# Angular - Pass the value of a function to mailto

Tags: angular

I am not understanding on how to pass the values from a function to mailto inside a link.

COMPONENT

```
  email() {
    for(let i = 0; i < this.clientInfo().length; i++) {
      this.uEmail = this.clientInfo()[i].email + ',';
      this.uEmails += this.uEmail;
    }
  }
```

HTML

```
<a href="mailto:{{this.uEmails}}">Email</a>
```

How can I invoke the email() function to get the values of uEmails without having to use something like a button click to invoke the email() function?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you could accomplish this. Here is one below. One thing to note from your question is that you don't use `this` to access a component properties within the HTML, that only needs to be done with in the JavaScript.

```
[href]="'mailto:' + uEmails"
```

Comment: Did not know ```this``` isn't needed.  Great to learn.  Your answer gives me null as the value

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke you function in ngOnInit function like shown below :

TS file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  uEmail;
  uEmails;
  clientInfo() {
    return [
      {
        email: 'test@test.com'
      },
      {
        email: 'test1@test.com'
      }
    ]
  }
  email() {
    this.uEmails = this.clientInfo().map((info) => info.email).join(',')
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.email();
  }
}
```

HTML file

```
<a href="mailto:{{this.uEmails}}">Email</a>
```

Check this working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tkjso1)